# Carousel prime vue width decreases

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, carousel, primevue

The first slide has a normal width, but each subsequent one has less and less. Although I strictly follow the doc(. Please help me figure it out.
link to the website: https://hydralux-74de0.web.app/

Here is my code:

```html
<Carousel :value="images" :numVisible="1" :numScroll="1">
    <template #item="slotProps">
      <div class="carousel-data">
         <img :src="slotProps.data.src" height="300">
      </div>
    </template>
</Carousel>
```

and

```js
const images = ref([
    {src: new URL('../assets/img/sewage-system/01.jpeg', import.meta.url)},
    {src: new URL('../assets/img/sewage-system/02.jpeg', import.meta.url)},
    {src: new URL('../assets/img/sewage-system/03.jpeg', import.meta.url)},
    {src: new URL('../assets/img/sewage-system/04.jpeg', import.meta.url)},
    {src: new URL('../assets/img/sewage-system/05.jpeg', import.meta.url)},
]);
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The issue is not that the width of the image is smaller, it's more of an issue with the slider itself (it's offsets to the right on each slide), inspect it with your devtools.